# looking for an easy way to check if date is greater than 30days out from today

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a simple way to check if a date of startDate is greater than 30days out from today.

```
<p ng-show="hasoffer && startDate > Date.today().add({days:30});">
```

Comment: What `Date` type are you using. Built-in `Date` in is neither has `today` nor `add` function.

Answer (score -1):

you can check if the month of start Date is greater than the current date and the days are equal to each other and the year start Date is less or equal to current
date if it's greater check the if the days are equal  hope I understood your question clearly :)

Comment: That doesn't work in December (January is going to be "less than" december). Or in a calendar system where months have different lengths. Eg February 1 + 30 days = March 2 or 3 depending on if it's a leap year.

Comment: then check the year also and the in the calendar system the difference is not too big 2days only will not effect

Comment: So maybe instead of arguing about it in the comments you should update your answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

You probably should make a function:

```
function getDateInThirtyDays(): Date {
  const dateInThirtyDays = new Date();
  dateInThirtyDays.setDate(dateInThirtyDays.getDate() + 30);

  return dateInThirtyDays;
}
```